# Magento 2: how to implement a translator

Tags: magento-2.1, frontend, language, transactional-mail

Is there any way to add a language translator in magento 2 (for frontend, customizable)?

I did't find any free extension for this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can add the text and the translated text in a csv file at this location. app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n/countrycde.csv. for example en_US.csv for English.

Comment: @ Sejal Shah how can i use it on frontend to select site language for a user

Comment: There is a setting in the configuration to set languages for your store. If you set that you will see a select drop down in the header.

Comment: @ Sejal Shah i have alredy set the language there in general-local option but the dropdown option not showing in header

Comment: Which theme you are using ? Your theme might not be supporting it. Switch to any magento default theme and check.